# Springfox Swagger 2 vs 3

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, springfox, spring-boot-2

Recently `Springfox Swagger 3` got released supporting `OpenAPI 3`. I was using `Springfox Swagger 2` quiet a while which gives all the necessary stuffs to document the REST API and nowwhen I upgrade now to 3, I could find the UI is bit changed when compared to the 2 version.

Can anyone please tell me whats the real benefit which I will get from Springfox Swagger 3. Also what exactly this `OpenAPI 3` specification really gives us to the Swagger API documentation

Comment: There are currently two major OpenAPI releases, 2.0 and 3.0. Version 3.1 was announced on June 18, 2020 as an initial release candidate. In [this post](https://stoplight.io/blog/difference-between-open-v2-v3-v31/), you will find some of the key differences between OpenAPI 2.0, 3.0, and 3.1.